# iOS app capable trick for external link doesn't work after jQuery update

Tags: jquery, ios5, jquery-mobile

I'm doing a jQuery Mobile / Rails app and I made it `app-capable` for iOS. The thing is, mobile apps for iOS don't support external link, all the link with `data-ajax="false"` as exemple.

So I use this little JS trick

```
if ( ("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone ) {
  $("a[data-ajax*=false]").live('click', function(){
    window.location.href=this.href;
    return false;
  });
}
```

It was working well since I update both jQuery and jQuery Mobile... Since that, nothing append when I click the links...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meh... Ok, I found the problem... It would seems that the last version of jQuery Mobile (1.1.0 RC1) has event on the link that modify them on the click... It made the `href` taking `#` as value...

I couldn't find how to stop it, so, I made a `data-href` attribute with the adress on the links and modify a bit my code

```
if ( ("standalone" in window.navigator) && window.navigator.standalone ) {
  $("a[data-ajax=false]").live('click', function(e){
    window.location.href=this.getAttribute('data-href');
    return false;
  });
}
```